# My friend starts at $(1,0)$ and moves up. I start at $(0,0)$ and continuously approach them at the same speed. What's the equation of my movement?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

My friend starts at $(1,0)$ and moves up. I start at $(0,0)$ and continuously approach them at the same speed. What's the equation of my movement?

Furthermore, let's say my equation of my movement is $f(x)$. **Then, what is $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$?**

I've determined that the equations can be determined by the following system of differential equations, where $x$ and $y$ represent coordinates and $t$ represents time:
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{t-y}{1-x}\right)\right)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{t-y}{1-x}\right)\right)$$
$$t_0 = 0, x_0 = 0, y_0 = 0$$
However, I do not know how to solve these equations. I am aware that $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{t-y}{1-x}$, but am unable to find $t$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.
Here is approximately the graph of my movement in a simulation:
[image]

Comment: By "move up" do you mean in the direction $(0, 1)?$

Comment: From $(1,0)$ to $(1,1)$

Comment: After attempts with separating variables, I'm not sure we can obtain a closed solution in this manner. I can attempt with power series, but it may not be useful or pretty.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractrix

Comment: I would expect a movement in the direction $45^0$ at the start and it makes sense that the convergence will be right behind with a distance of 1 behind.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PursuitCurve.html

Comment: Look up the curve of pursuit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation for $t$ is the arclength
$$t = \int_0^x \sqrt{\left(y'(s)\right)^2 + 1}\,\rm{d}s.$$

Therefore, if we re-arrange the equation $y' = \frac{t-y}{1-x}$,
$$(1-x)y' + y = \int_0^x\sqrt{\left(y'(s)\right)^2 + 1}\,\rm{d}s.$$

Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$:
$$(1-x)y'' = \sqrt{(y')^2+1}$$
which, if we write $u = y'$, gives
$$\frac{u'}{\sqrt{u^2+1}} = \frac1{1-x},$$
which as you can see is separable.  Integrating both sides gives
$$\sinh^{-1}(u) = C-\ln(1-x)$$
or
$$y' = \sinh(C - \ln(1-x)) = \frac12e^{-C}\left(x-1\right) + \frac{e^C}{2(1-x)}$$

Integrating again gives the answer.

---

Finding the unknown constants by using $y(0)=y'(0) = 0$ yields
$$y = \frac14x^2 - \frac12x - \frac12\ln(1-x)$$

From here, it's routine to show
$$\int_0^1 y\,\rm{d}x = \frac13$$

and for an extra,
$$\lim_{x\to1^-} t-y = \lim_{x\to1^-}(1-x)y' = \frac12$$
which means we get arbitrarily close to $1/2$ a unit from our friend, but never closer.